# Trying to bind a combobox to an enum in C#

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a class that contains a property that is an enum:

```
public RaTypes RaBucket1Type { get; set; }
```

My enum is:

```
    public enum RaTypes
{
    Red,
    Yellow
}
```

I was able to bind a form's combobox data-source to the enum so that when I click on the drop-down, I see the enumerations:

```
cmbBucket1Type.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(RaTypes));
```

When I load the form, I would like to populate the combo-box with the existing value.  I have tried the following:

```
        cmbBucket1Type.DisplayMember = "TradeType";
        cmbBucket1Type.ValueMember = "TradeEnumID";
        cmbBucket1Type.SelectedValue = EditedAlgorithm.RaBucket1Type;
```

But this did not work.

Also, I'm not sure I have implemented the ValueChanged event handler correctly either:

```
EditedAlgorithm.RaBucket1Type = (RaTypes)((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem;
```

Can someone help me understand:

1. How to set the combobox to current value, and
2. How to handle the event handler so I can set the property to whatever was selected?

Thanks
-Ed

**UPDATES**
I have tried

```
    cmbBucket1Type.SelectedIndex = cmbBucket1Type.FindString(EditedAlgorithm.RaBucket1Type.ToString());
```

and

```
    cmbBucket1Type.SelectedItem = EditedAlgorithm.RaBucket1Type;
```

Neither works.

Comment: This is Windows Forms right?

Comment: The question _When I load the form, I would like to populate the combo-box with the existing value._ does not make a lot of sense. In a `ComboBox`, the world _populate_ means _add items_ to the `ComboBox`. Are you trying to select the last value displayed at load time?

Comment: I would like:  When the form loads, add value of existing class property.  When user clicks the down-arrow, all enum values are offered (displayed).

Comment: Yes, Windows form.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're using the terminology a little differently than normal, which makes it difficult to understand.

Normally, the terms *Add*, *Populate*, and *Select* are used to mean the following:

- Add - Add an item to the existing set of items in the combo box.
- Populate - Initialize the combo box with a set of items.
- Select (Display) - Choose one among many items in the combo box as the selected item. Normally this item will be displayed in the combo box visible area.

Having cleared that up, I assume following is what you want to do.

1. Initially *populate* the `ComboBox` with a set of values. In your case, values of `RaType` `Enum`.
2. Create an instance of your class which contains the property mentioned. Since you didn't name that class I'll simply name it `SomeClass`.
3. Initialize the `RaBucket1Type` property of the said class instance with an `enum` value of your choice. I'll initialize it to `Yellow`.
4. Have the `ComboBox` *select* the said value at start up.
5. After `Form_Load`, at any given time, if the user changes the value of the `ComboBox`, have the change reflected in your class instance property.

For that, I would do something like this:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    // Your class instance.
    private SomeClass InstanceOfSomeClass = null;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Initialize the RaBucket1Type property with Yellow.
        InstanceOfSomeClass = new SomeClass(RaTypes.Yellow);
        // Populating the ComboBox
        comboBox1.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(RaTypes));
    }

    // At selected index changed event
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the selected value.
        var selected = comboBox1.SelectedValue;
        // Change the `RaBucket1Type` value of the class instance according to the user choice.
        InstanceOfSomeClass.RaBucket1Type = (RaTypes)selected;
    }

    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // At form load time, set the `SelectedItem` of the `ComboBox` to the value of `RaBucket1Type` of your class instance.
        // Since we initialized it to `Yellow`, the `ComboBox` will show `Yellow` as the selected item at load time.
        if (InstanceOfSomeClass != null)
        {
            comboBox1.SelectedItem = InstanceOfSomeClass.RaBucket1Type;
        }
    }
}

public enum RaTypes
{
    Red,
    Yellow
}

public class SomeClass
{
    public RaTypes RaBucket1Type { get; set; }

    public SomeClass(RaTypes raTypes) { RaBucket1Type = raTypes; }
}
```

Please do keep in mind this is a basic example to show you how to handle the situation and not a complete finished code. You'll need to do a bunch of error checks to make sure class instances and selected items are not null etc.

Comment: THANK YOU!... I have actually tried this (SelectedItem=...) but for some reason it is not working.   I will do some more debugging and post what I find (hopefully an answer).   The VERY strange aspect I am noticing during debug is that as I populate the combobox by assigning its datasource (as you show above), I see the class property change.   Very strange behavior since the two should not be related.   I love/hate these bugs :)

Answer (score 1):

I FOUND MY ANSWER:

I had the SelectedIndexChanged event pointing to my event handler which means that when I "added" items to the ComboBox using:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(RaTypes));
```

it was triggering the event handler, and resetting my class property.  My event handler was this:

```
var selectedValue = cmbBucket1Type.SelectedValue;
```

So the simple solution was to:

1. Remove the hard-coded event handler from the Visual Studio GUI.
2. Add the following event handler in code **AFTER** I assign the DataSource

   *bucketType1.SelectedIndexChanged += BucketTypeChanged;*

This worked.

THANK YOU ALL FOR HELPING!!

-Ed

Comment: If you need to re-load your comboBox1, you can `-=` disable the changed event handler, reload, `+=` enable the changed event handler. Be sure to Not have multiple `+=` *hooks* for the event handler by `-=` removing the event handler first.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the *selectedValue* like this:

```
cmbBucket1Type.SelectedValue = EditedAlgorithm.RaBucket1Type;
```

And you can handle the selected value when the combo change like this:

```
        private void cmbBucket1Type_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedValue = cmbBucket1Type.SelectedValue;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for responding but I do not see a difference between your suggestion and what I said I tried and did not work? "cmbBucket1Type.SelectedValue = EditedAlgorithm.RaBucket1Type;" is precisely what i tried... Is there a typo??